# Numeric keyboard in md-datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

How to call the numeric keyboard in md-datepicker?

```
<md-datepicker id="xs-datepicker" name="date" ng-model="vm.entryDate" md-max-date="vm.now" required flex=50></md-datepicker>
```

The alpha numeric keypad appears by default when editing the md-datepicker on mobile phones. How can I call the numeric keypad instead of the alpha numeric keypad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweaking a [question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38695024/782358) yesterday to access the `input` of the date picker one can set its type to be number so when one views this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/akaBqy) on a mobile phone, tapping the `input` brings up the numeric keypad. Is that what you mean? Tapping the calendar icon does not bring up a keyboard on my phone.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" style="padding: 40px;" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content>
    <md-datepicker id="myDatePicker" ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $element) {
    $scope.myDate = new Date();
    var myDatePicker = angular.element($element[0].querySelector('#myDatePicker'));
    var myDatePickerInputContainer = angular.element(myDatePicker[0].children[1]);
    var myDatePickerInput = angular.element(myDatePickerInputContainer[0].children[0]);
    myDatePickerInput.attr("type", "number");
});
```

Comment: Yes exactly! Thanks

Comment: I used attribute 'tel' instead of 'number' - 'myDatePickerInput.attr("type", "tel"); ' So that I can also select the date from the calender.

Comment: @Veela Just tried that but get an alpha numeric keypad. Anyway, glad it works for you.